# Laravel 5.2 query string is empty

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a problem with laravel where the query string shows empty:

If I do /en/news/some-news-slug, it gets the input as needed. However, if I do /en/news?page=2, it doesn't show that I have 'page' query string parameter. Here is my nginx configuration:

conf.d/php.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

server:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        # root and servername hidden

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
        }
        index index.php;
        include conf.d/php.conf;

}
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->query());
    $posts = $this->post->paginate(App::getLocale(), 2);
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo $post->id. ' ';
    }

    die;
}
```

Comment: If you want the querystring variable "page", you should probably look for `$request->page` or `$request->input('page')`. Does either of those get the right variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your NGINX config to

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

The change is in the **$is_args**